# Interaction between CSS grid and mixed shadowDOM/lightDOM

Tags: javascript, html, css-grid, shadow-dom, custom-element

I am currently experimenting with slots in custom elements.

See this simple example:

```js
customElements.define('x-y', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let template = document.createElement('template');
    template.innerHTML = `<style>
    :host { display: block; align-self: normal; }
    div {
      background-color: #666;
      color: white;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <div>affected by styles from ShadowDOM</div>
  <slot name="content"></slot>`;

    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  border: 2px dashed magenta;
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(0, 1fr);
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

x-y>div {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<x-y class="inner-grid">
  <div slot="content">not affected by styles from ShadowDOM</div>
</x-y>
```

As we can see, the grid definition for `.inner-grid`, although defined in the page's CSS, *does* affect the displaying of the content of the shadowDOM.

This, though handy, came kind of unexpected, as outside CSS should not affect the internals of a web component (the exceptions being inherited properties and custom properties).

The second expectation I had - that is also violated - is that a grid container makes it so its **direct children** become grid cells, to which the grid-template definitions apply, if any. How is an element inside the shadowDOM such a direct child?

This is the structure in Chrome's element inspector:

[image: DOM structure]

**Q:** Can someone shed some light on *exactly how this works*? How does CSS grid interact with shadow DOM / light DOM mixed content? Please add reference, if any is available.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your question by using my own code.

So I put your `.inner-grid` on the 3 column grid `<game-board>` element

Your question #1

> As we can see, the grid definition for .inner-grid, although defined
> in the page's CSS, does affect the displaying of the content of the
> shadowDOM.

Where do you see *this affects the content of the shadowDOM"*?

The red background is what you mean?

The shadowRoot is considered an element, taking up space, thus is **1fr**

Then `display:grid; grid-template-rows:repeat( 3 , 1fr );` **on the container** will extend the container to 3 times (thus indirect its shadowRoot) height.

Your question #2

> The second expectation I had - that is also violated - is that a grid
> container makes it so its direct children become grid cells, to which
> the grid-template definitions apply, if any. How is an element inside
> the shadowDOM such a direct child?

SLOTs (or actually the slotted content/"*distributed nodes*") are the direct children in the grid

```
    <slot name="A1"></slot>  <slot name="A2"></slot>            <slot></slot>
    <slot name="B1"></slot>  <span>gridded in shadowDOM</span>  <slot name="B2"></slot>
```

work as a 3x2 grid

Note:

- There is **nothing** in *SLOT* A2, it does not fill a grid area
- The 2 elements from lightDOM go to the default slot `<slot></slot>` and fill **2** grid areas.

```html
<template id=GAME-BOARD>
  <style description="style shadowDOM">
    div {
      background: lightgreen;
      display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr)  }
    ::slotted(*) { border: 3px dashed green }
  </style>
  <div>
    <slot name="A1"></slot> <slot name="A2"></slot>           <slot></slot>
    <slot name="B1"></slot> <span>gridded in shadowDOM</span> <slot name="B2"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<style description="lightDOM game-pieces">
 game-board{ background:red; display:grid; grid-template-rows:repeat(3,1fr)}
 game-piece{ background:lightblue }
</style>
<game-board>
  <game-piece>to default slot!</game-piece>
  <game-piece slot="A1"></game-piece>
  <game-piece slot="B2"></game-piece>
  <div>GRIDDED from ligthDOM to default slot</div>
</game-board>
<script>
  customElements.define('game-board', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
             .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
    }})
  customElements.define('game-piece', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      this.innerHTML = this.getAttribute("slot") || "NO SLOT";
    }})
</script>
```

---

If you want to create a Chessboard, you need to put an Element in **every** of the 64 SLOTs by default. These are also required to capture drag/touch movements.

It is easier to work with named `grid-template-areas` (in shadowDOM) then.

[image]

And position with (64) CSS Selectors:

```
 ::slotted([slot="A5"]){ grid-area:A5 }
```

And use the default `<slot></slot>` to capture pieces not positioned on the board.

I did a [Chessboard](https://chessmeister.github.io) with Components 2 years ago: https://chessmeister.github.io (not using everything I know now)